# In SQL how to count the number of result?

Tags: sql

I'm having the following SQL DB:

DB name: `films`

```
DB fields: id, title, release_year, country, duration, language, certification, gross, budget
```

I'm trying to solve the following question:
Count in how many different years were more than 200 movies released?

I have tried to run the following SQL query:

```
SELECT release_year
FROM films
GROUP BY release_year
HAVING COUNT(release_year) > 200;
```

But I'm getting the years that have released after 2000. (total there are 13 results)
When trying to use `SELECT count(release_year)` 
I'm not getting `13` (I'm getting count for each year)

so how can I count the total number of results ?

Comment: Use the current query as a subquery. count() its result.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elegant way to solve your problem, if your database support analytic functions:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) OVER() AS num_movies
FROM films
GROUP BY release_year
HAVING COUNT(*) > 200;
```

The above is for SQL Server, on MySQL 8+ and Postgres use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER() AS num_movies
FROM films
GROUP BY release_year
HAVING COUNT(*) > 200
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, the question requests the count of the years, which implies a single row, this returns multiple rows.

Comment: Hmm, is returning multiple rows in SQL Server 2019 for me?

Comment: You are correct, I should have used `TOP` or `LIMIT` in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like using the `WITH` statement as

```
WITH atable AS (SELECT release_year, COUNT(*)
FROM films
GROUP BY release_year
HAVING COUNT(release_year) > 200)

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM atable;
```